# How to get the height and width of the notification bar in android?

Tags: android, notifications, size, screen

So i know how to get the screen size of an android device.

But how do i get the the size of the notification bar which comes in the top?

```
   DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600713/size-of-android-notification-bar-and-title-bar

Answer (score 1):

This question was already answered : [Height of status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android)

**But you can do this like this :**

```
Rect rectgle= new Rect();
Window window= getWindow();
window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
int StatusBarHeight= rectgle.top;
int contentViewTop= 
    window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
int TitleBarHeight= contentViewTop - StatusBarHeight;

   Log.i("*** Jorgesys :: ", "StatusBar Height= " + StatusBarHeight + " , TitleBar Height = " + TitleBarHeight);
```