# Android - Height of title bar

Tags: android, runnable, titlebar

I want to get the title bar height (not the status bar)

I need this in order to know the real height the app can use.

I saw on SO some code and I tried it and it returned height=0.

So, I did some more search and I found that I have to put it inside a runnable and call it with a post-delayed.

Here is the code:

```
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {  
        @Override  
        public void run() {  
            Rect frame = new Rect();  
            getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);  
            int titleHeight = frame.top;  
            Log.d(TAG, titleHeight); 
        }  
    };  

    mHandler.postDelayed (r, 200);
```

This is working. The `Log.D` shows the correct height, But now there is a new problem.
I cannot use the titleHeight variable for further programming **inside my onCreate.**

What to do?

Thanks,
AJ

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of android notification bar and title bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600713/size-of-android-notification-bar-and-title-bar)

Answer (score 0):

The scope of that variable is inside the run method.  If you want to reference that variable, you should change it to a larger scope (define it outside of this method).

Comment: I did. But outside the runnable, the variable is zero! and not the real calculated height...

Comment: this is because is postDelayed

Comment: You still need to set the value of the variable, but it needs to be scoped outside that method to access it elsewhere.

Comment: @Deuterium, so what it the solution to be possible to use it outside of the runnable? I already defined it outside of the runnable.

Comment: @Deuterium, the other question suggest using known title heights. I want to calculate it.

Comment: @AJGottes why calculate a fixed height?